# Ubuntu 16.04 suddenly starts booting into Kodibuntu or something like it

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, boot, kodi

Last week, I saw a dropdown next to the login field for Ubuntu with a few "boot options" or something like that, one of them being Kodi. I was curious and wanted to see what it was so I picked Kodi and rebooted. Nothing happened, and I forgot about it.

Today I had to reboot for another reason and Ubuntu is now booting into a fullscreen version of kodi (Kodibuntu?) with seemingly no way to exit. I can't alt-tab, I can't open a terminal (neither ctrl-alt-t or f1/f4 work). I looked in the system settings and I see no way to revert it. I can see that my document's are still there using Kodi's file browser but can't access any of them. I really need this fixed today, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://kodi.wiki/view/kodibuntu#Basic_use) documentation on kodibuntu for how to swap back
[image][image: Change back in the top right of the log in screen]

you can exit the full screen version of kodibuntu by following the steps outlined in the link above.
Sorry if this is unclear but a screenshot would be useful to know what screen you're on.

Comment: I don't know how I had some sort of blind spot for the exit button. That should have been Obvious. Thanks.